# JBoss: switch domain in case of failure

Tags: failover, jboss

In a cluster configuration of 2 different physical servers, managed with the domain setup, where one of the servers is the master and acts as a domain and the other is the slave and gets the configuration from the master, what is the correct procedure in case of failure of the master? In that case I'd like to make the slave behave as master, so I can access the admin console (typically in port 9990) and manage the configuration.

I've already found out that if you start the slave domain with the 'backup' option (bin/domain.sh -backup), the slave creates the file 'domain/configuration/domain.cached-remote.xml', with the latest current configuration from the master. With this file It's probably going to be easy to start the slave as a master. But for that I need to stop the slave, breaking the HA. Any suggestion on this ?

I just want to add that if you have the cached version of the configuration above, you can start the slave with this file, without trying to contact the master with "bin/domain.sh --cached-dc". Yet this doesn't solve anything, because this implies restarting the slave server and it would be still a slave server (breaking HA), and the management via web or cli would still be blocked because the server would still consider himself slave.